# DevExpress - Formating the string of the expression in Style Format Condition

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I'm trying to format the string in the expression for the Style Format Condition to paint the background color of the cell with some color if the condition it's true. My condition it's only to compare if the substraction of two values is equal to another value, I execute the comparison like this because the values are double and it's necessary to avoid precision errors, where EPSILON is 0.001:

```cs
if (Math.Abs(rvalue - tara - value) > EPSILON)
{
   // do something
}
```

I'm trying this code , but doesn't work, please if someone can do this, please help me. Thanks

```cs
var condExpression = new StyleFormatCondition(FormatConditionEnum.Expression);
condExpression.Column = gv_MateriaPrima.Columns[3];
condExpression.Appearance.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
condExpression.Expression = String.Format("Abs([FieldName] - {0} - {1}) > {2}",
value1, value2, EPSILON);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added your format condition into [GridView.FormatConditions](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_FormatConditionstopic) collection?
Here is the code snippet that works correctly to me (please check the differences with your code):

```
// just sample data
gridControl1.DataSource = new List<DataObj> { 
    new DataObj() { RValue = 0.2 }, 
    new DataObj() { RValue = 0.21 },  // !!! Orange
    new DataObj() { RValue = 0.201 }, // !!! Orange
    new DataObj() { RValue = 0.2001 },
    new DataObj() { RValue = 0.20001 },  
};
gridView1.PopulateColumns();

//...
var condExpression = new StyleFormatCondition(FormatConditionEnum.Expression);
condExpression.Column = gridView1.Columns["RValue"];
condExpression.Appearance.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
condExpression.Appearance.Options.UseBackColor = true;
condExpression.Expression = String.Format("Abs([RValue] - {0} - {1}) > {2}", 0.1, 0.1, EPSILON);
gridView1.FormatConditions.Add(condExpression);

//...
class DataObj {
    public double RValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: yes I have added theformat condition into the GridView.FormatConditions collection. The problem was the data type of the column was String and the expression doesn't work